# Расстановка знаков препинания в предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

1. "Учитывая <...>, просим проинформировать состоит ли данная семья на особом учете как неблагополучная?" Нужна ли запятая после слова информировать?
2. "Поступило обращение с вопросами суть которых установить не представляется возможным". Нужна ли запятая после слова вопросами?

Comment: Пожалуйста, создавайте для каждой темы отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

1. Корректно: "Учитывая..., просим проинформировать, (между грамматическими основами) состоит ли данная семья на особом учете (*как* в значении *в качестве*) как неблагополучная?"
2. Корректно: "Поступило обращение с вопросами, (между грамматическими основами) суть которых установить не представляется возможным".

Answer (score 1):

Оба предложения - СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.
Придаточное предложение отделяется от главного.

> Придаточные изъяснительные могут прикрепляться к главному предложению
> с помощью:
>
> союзов (*что, чтобы, как, будто, как будто*),
>
> союза-частицы ***ли***,
>
> союзных слов (*кто, что, **который**, какой, чей, где, куда, откуда, когда,*
> *зачем, почему* и др.).
>
> Союзы и союзные слова обычно стоят в начале придаточного предложения.
> Именно по ним достаточно легко определить границу между главным и
> придаточным предложениями. Но союз-частица ***ли*** всегда находится в
> середине придаточного изъяснительного.

**[источник](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/738-222_pridatochnye_dopolnitelnye_izyasnitelnye.html)**

В Ваших примерах:

1. *Учитывая <...>, просим проинформировать, состоит **ли** данная семья на особом учете как неблагополучная?*
2. *Поступило обращение с вопросами, суть **которых** установить не представляется возможным.*